# iphone inapp purchase programming ? how to get statistical information from apple

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4, ios-4.2

I am developing a simple Fund raising app which hold 4 batches (Keep 10$,20$,30$,40$). people who willing to donate will buy these batches through in app purchase.

My concern here is ....  is it possible for iphone client to get statistical information from apple through code. I do agree that i can see statistical information if i login through ituneconnect. I just want to get through code so that i can display inside my app.

Note: I know that i can have my own server to store statistical info. i don't want to do that because its a small app

please suggest me regarding this.

Thanks in advance

jenie

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean stats as in how many people have bought each tier?

You can't get that information programmatically for a couple reasons. First it isn't available until the next day, second it is only available via itunesconnect and apps are prohibited from scraping apple sites.

You would need to setup a server to host the statistics and update the server every morning with the new stats.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Apple Guidelines your app probably wouldn't be accepted to the store
([link](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html))

**20. Contests, sweepstakes, lotteries, and raffles**

20.1 Sweepstakes and contests must be sponsored by the developer/company of the app

20.2 Official rules for sweepstakes and contests, must be presented in the app and make it clear that Apple is not a sponsor or involved in the activity in any manner

20.3 It must be permissible by law for the developer to run a lottery app, and a lottery app must have all of the following characteristics: consideration, chance, and a prize

20.4 Apps that allow a user to directly purchase a lottery or raffle ticket in the app will be rejected

**21. Charities and contributions**

21.1 Apps that include the ability to make donations to recognized charitable organizations must be free

21.2 The collection of donations *must be done via a web site in Safari or an SMS*